# How to pulse an image and change the rate of pulsing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think this is working but not really. I also don't think that it is the best approach.

The timer serves as another function running while having the ability to change the pulsing rate of the image.

I have tried to use gifs instead of because they have different speeds, there isn't a smooth transition when switching between images.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <style>
            #red-square {
                position: absolute;
                display: inline-block;
                z-index: 1;
                top  : 200px;
                right: 200px;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <div id="red-square"></div>
        <button onclick="speedOne();">speed one</button>
        <button onclick="speedTwo();">speed two</button>
        <button onclick="speedThree();">speed three</button>
        <script>

    var counter          = 0,
        stopTimeoutTwo   = null,
        stopTimeoutThree = null,
        currentSpeed     = "speed one";

    function runCounter() {
        counter++;
        result.textContent = counter;
        if(currentSpeed == "speed one") {
            if((counter%60) == 0) {
                $("#red-square").hide();
            }else if((counter%60) != 0) {
                $("#red-square").show();
            }
        }
        else if(currentSpeed = "speed two") {
            if((counter%45)  == 0) {
                $("#red-square").hide();
            }else if((counter % 45) != 0) {
                $("#red-square").show();
            }
        }else if(currentSpeed = "speed three") {
            if((counter%30)  == 0) {
                $("#red-square").hide();
            }else if((counter%30) != 0) {
                $("#red-square").show();
            }
        }
        if(counter < 1e5) timer = setTimeout(runCounter, 0);
    }

    runCounter();

    function stepOne() {
        currentSpeed = "speed one";
    }
    function stepTwo() {
        currentSpeed = "speed two";
    }
    function stepThree() {
        currentSpeed = "speed three";
    }

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use __[setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)__ and when click on the speeds, change the interval...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setInterval to create your efect like so:  **[Fiddle!](https://fiddle.jshell.net/diego_carrascal/aygoenjd/4/)**

This is the JS I used:

```
 var speed = 4000;
 var inter;
 var square = document.getElementById("red-square");
 square.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 function myTime(){
  inter = setInterval(function(){ 
          console.log(square.style.backgroundColor+" "+speed);
      if(square.style.backgroundColor == "red"){
         square.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      }
      else{
         square.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
   }, speed);
} 

function changSpeed(s){
  clearInterval(inter);
  speed = s;
  inter=null;
  myTime();
}
myTime();
```

the rest is your code.